# Install Cordova plugin using specific commit from GitHub project

Tags: git, cordova, github, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I used `cordova plugin add https://github.com/photomania/cordova-plugin-camera.git` to add a Cordova plugin in my Ionic project.

Now I need this fixed version: https://github.com/photomania/cordova-plugin-camera/commit/cbb3e5011bb04245b421ba6cd9ad456904bf7ef9

I have already tried `cordova plugin add https://github.com/photomania/cordova-plugin-camera#cbb3e5011bb04245b421ba6cd9ad456904bf7ef9`

but it returned the error:

```
fatal: reference is not a tree: cbb3e5011bb04245b421ba6cd9ad456904bf7ef9`
```

How do I install the right version from GitHub?

Comment: that's the right way, it fails for some strange reason.

Comment: I have the same problem as you. Did you solve your problem ? If so can you share your solution please ? Thank you